# Ignore duplicates and not deleting them

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, duplicates

I already know how to delete duplicate rows on an `Id` column. But I am not allowed to delete anything on the server. What I need is a `WITH` statement that ignores duplicate rows (takes only one of them). Is there a way to do this without modifying data in a table?

P.S.1 All the duplicates rows are identical. So there is no need to decide which one to keep.

P.S.2 I'd rather not create an extra temp table (`SELECT * INTO ...`)

Comment: Table schema please?

Comment: @Arion any table with a duplicate value on `Id` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CTE which does a select `DISTINCT` on all columns:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT Id, col1, col2, ..., colN
    FROM yourTable
)
```

You could also achieve this using `GROUP BY` on all columns:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Id, col1, col2, ..., colN
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Id, col1, col2, ..., colN
)
```

If the `Id` values are *not* duplicated, but all other columns are, then you can try:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT MIN(Id) AS Id, col1, col2, ..., colN
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY col1, col2, ..., colN
)
```

Comment: I'll try it right away and come back to you. Thanks!

Comment: @Disasterkid Are the `Id` values unique, or are they duplicate as well?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The entire row is duplicate. That means there are duplicate `Id`s as well.

Comment: @Disasterkid Then go with the first or second option I gave you.

Comment: Thank you @TimBiegeleisen! have temporarily lost access to the server. Will check as soon as I am in.